# Linux doesn't work on Asus

Tags: system-installation, graphics, asus

I bought an Asus notebook (model z450l) and the computer comes with Windows pre-installed. Every time I try to install some Linux distribution the system runs normally for the first few hours, but when I turn off my computer and turn on the machine again, the system either displays a fatal error, gets stuck on the login screen, or just doesn't run the graphics module.

```
rumblefish@rumbleCPT:~$ lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics (rev 09)
        Subsystem: ASUSTek Computer Inc. Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics
        Kernel driver in use: i915
```

----UPDATED----

Attention : Labels in Brazilian-Portuguese

```
root@Cerberus:/home/rumblefish# sudo lshw | grep -A9 firmware
    *-firmware
        descriçao:BIOS
        fabricante:American Megatrends Inc.
        ID físico: 0
        Versao: Z450LA.204
        date: 08/12/2015
        tamanho: 64KiB
        capacidade: 6400KiB
        capacidades: pci upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect socketedrom edd init13floopy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer acpi usb smartbattery biosbootspecification uefi

    *-cache:0
--
    configuracao: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8402-1_0.0.1 10/26/11 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
    recursos: irq:47 porta de E/S:4000(tamanho=256) memória:b2110000-b2110fff memória:d0000000-d0003fff

    *-pci:2
        descriçao: PCI bridge
        produto: Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #4
        fabricante: Intel Corporation
        ID físico: 1c.3
        Informaçoes do barramento: pci@0000:00:1c.3
        versao: e3
        largura: 32 bits
--
            configuraçao: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8723be driverversion=4.4.0-45-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.0.4 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
            recursos: irq:19 porta de E/S:3000(tamanho=256) memória:b20000000-b2003fff

    *-isa
        descriçao: ISA bridge
        produto: Wildcat Point-LP LPC Controller
        fabricante: Intel Corporation
        ID físico: 1f
        informaçoes do barramento: pci@0000:00:1f.0
        versao: 03
        largura: 32bits
```

Comment: Do you mind adding a screenshot of what the error is?

Comment: i'll try to find some error message. but at the last installation, the system doesnt show any error message... just appear a black screen after system load. which log file can i look?

Comment: If you mean turn on PC, boot Ubuntu and a blank, black screen, then you may have [a list of causes](http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it).

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'` terminal command.

Comment: May need boot parameter like pci=nomsi? Asus x555u w/o pci=nomsi - space issue on drive and runaway log files filling drive
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2327103&page=3 and: 
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2327570

Comment: i'm at work now... but i'll post the screenshot when i arrive home. 
I'm worried about my computer does not support linux, since no distribution worked properly.

Comment: There's a rumor that some systems were shipped with a UEFI BIOS that was so crippled it could only run Windows. I can neither confirm nor deny this ATM. It might be helpful to  [edit] your question and include the output of  `sudo lshw | grep -A9 firmware` While your at it you might narrow it down. Specify what version of Ubuntu you are trying to install, and what you observed when you tried. thank you for helping us help you! I don't think you've yet had the chance to review http://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask